# Uploading images with HTMX in django

Tags: django, django-templates, htmx

I am trying to implement image adding functionality through HTMX. Adding the photo is no problem. However, once the photo is added in the view, the image link does not show up. It looks like no photo has been added but when I hit the refresh button, the link is being displayed. What I am trying to achieve is that, once the photo is uploaded and the form is saved, I want the link to show up to confirm for the user that their photo is uploaded.

This is my form template

```
<form action='' method="POST" class="form" hx-post='' hx-swap='outerHTML' enctype="multipart/form-data"
    hx-post="{{request.path}}"
    hx-encoding="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{field}}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    
    

    <div class='htmx-indicator'>Loading...</div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class='htmx-inverted-indicator' style='margin-top:10px;' type='submit' >Save</button>
      </div>
    
    {% if message %}
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    
</form>
```

I am then including this template in the update template.

Is there anyway to get the wished result without using JavaScript?

**EDIT**
This is the view function

```
@login_required
def workout_update_view(request, id=None):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Workout, id=id, pt=request.user.pt.id)
    form = WorkoutForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=obj) 
    new_exercise_url = reverse("train:hx-exercise-create", kwargs={"parent_id": obj.id})
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "object": obj,
        "new_exercise_url": new_exercise_url
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        context['message'] = 'Updated!'
    if request.htmx:
       return render(request, "train/komponents/forms.html", context)
    return render(request, "train/workout_update.html", context)
```

Comment: Do you want to replace this form with the link of the uploaded image (returned by the view function)?

Comment: @Dauros No I want to display it in the field of the image as it's instance. Like the other values of the form are displayed.

Comment: Currently I don't see where do you want to display the submitted form values. This form does not have a `hx-target` attribute, so HTMX will not replace anything with the returned content from the backend. Could you share the relevant part of the view function?

Comment: @Dauros I don't want HTMX to change anything, I only want to dynamically update the form with HTMX. I added the view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the element (in your case: the form) that submits the HTMX request, you still need to add `hx-target="this"`, where [`this` is a special target](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-target/) that points to itself (the element having the `hx-target="this"` attribute). After the request, HTMX will swap the old form with the updated one.

```
<form action='' 
      method="POST" 
      class="form" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      hx-post="{{request.path}}"
      hx-target="this"
      hx-swap="outerHTML" 
      hx-encoding="multipart/form-data">
```

#### Edit:

After the `form.save()` the `Workform` model will receive the uploaded image, but we need to trigger a refresh from the DB via [deleting the `image_field` property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database) of `obj`. After this, accessing `obj.image_field.url` will fetch the new value from the database.

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    del obj.image_field
    context['message'] = 'Updated!'
```

And in the template:

```
<form>
  ...
  {% if object.image_field.url %}
  <a href="{{ object.image_field.url }}">{{ object.image_field.url }}</a>
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it does still not work. The link does still not show up when the form is being submitted.

Comment: Right, I missed that you did not displaying `new_exercise_url` (assuming this is the "image link") in the form template. You need to add it somewhere, see my edited answer.

Comment: The `new_exercise_url` has nothing to do with the image. The image belongs to the whole workout, which is like the "parent" which consists of exercises. With image link I mean the path to the image. And by doing like this, when I refresh the page I get two links.

Comment: Ok. So could you tell me after a form submission where do you store/create exactly the "image link" you want to display? Somewhere in `obj`?

Comment: I store the images in the 'static' directory which is over 'images' and 'workouts' so it looks like this `static/images/workouts/` and then the name of the file.

Comment: In your question you mentioned that after a page refresh "the link is being displayed", How do you create that link? You just need to pass this link to `context` and display in the form template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245047/discussion-between-randommadi-and-dauros).

Answer (score 0):

You could add an empty HttpResponse with an event *formSubmittedEvent*

```py
if form.is_valid():
    from django_htmx.http import trigger_client_event
    form.save()
    context['message'] = 'Updated!'
    response = HttpResponse()
    trigger_client_event(response, "formSubmittedEvent", { },)
    return response
```

You need then to trigger that event from the client side and a view to handle that reponse is also needed:

```html
<div  hx-get="{% url 'myapp:my-uploaded-image' %}"
    hx-trigger="formSubmittedEvent from:body" >
</div>
```

```py
def my_image_url_view(request, any_args_needed):
    # your logic here, get obj...
    return render("myapp/snippets/image_template.html", {'obj': obj}
```

In *myapp/snippets/image_template.html*

```html
<img src={{obj.image.url}} alt="No image">
```

Check more here: https://github.com/ramiboutas/ramiboutas/blob/main/my_cheat_sheets/htmx/README.md#send-a-trigger-from-the-server-and-capture-it-from-the-client-later